# extracting all instances of subclass from arraylist

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have `ArrayList<Unit> units`. I want to write a function that would return all objects of specified subclass, which is used as parameter. However I can't get it to work. Here is what I have:

```
public static ArrayList<? extends Unit> getTheseUnits(Class<? extends Unit> specific_unit) {
    ArrayList<specific_unit> res = new ArrayList<>();  //'specific_unit' is in red here. Adding '.class' or '.getClass()' after it does not resolve anything
    for (Unit u : units){
        if (u instanceof specific_unit){
            res.add(u);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: "It is red in here" translates to a compiler error. Maybe you should really learn some java basics before trying to work on such code. Meaning: learn about elemental concepts like compiler errors (and how to read them), before turning to sophisticated usage of generic types! Your "red in here" boils down to: you can't use a variable name as generic type, thus `ArrayList <specific_unit>` is not a correct Java declaration.

Comment: @Jägermeister I understand that it is compiler error, however eclipse does not help much by just stating that `specific_unit cannot be resolved`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter them by class:

```
public static List<Unit> getUnitsByClass(Class<? extends Unit> specificClass, List<? extends Unit> units) {
     return units.stream()
                 .filter(e -> e.getClass().equals(specificClass))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If you want to make this method parametrized, use another option:

```
public static <T extends Unit> List<T> getUnitsByClass(Class<T> specificClass, List<? extends Unit> units) {
     return (List<T>) units.stream()
                           .filter(e -> e.getClass().equals(specificClass))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

but in the second approach, you will get unchecked cast warning.

Comment: I think your answer is a bit short. It seems that he has no understanding at all of generic types; therefore he might not be able to grasp that your "SpecificUnit.class" is something else than his "specific_unit" variable.

Comment: @Jägermeister OP's `specific_unit` variable is of type class, I renamed it to `specificClass` to make more clear.

Comment: @Jägermeister maybe I don't get how to get generics right all the time, but I'm not dumb.

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino I didnt mean to insult you. But you are correct; I could/should have suggested to improve the answer "in general" (and not implying that you specifically might have a problem there)

Comment: @Jägermeister I performed some improvement to my answer, if you have something to add, feel free to comment/edit.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `instanceof` on variable. Instead, you should use `isInstance`.

Simply replace this line:

```
if (u instanceof specific_unit) {
```

with

```
if (specific_unit.isInstance(u)){
```

Comment: Just for completeness: his method will still not compile, as he is also using specific_unit as type parameter when creating the "return value" arraylist. You might want to update your answer regarding that aspect, too.

Answer (score 2):

If you change your method signature it can work:

```
public static <T extends Unit> ArrayList<T> getTheseUnits(Class<T> specific_unit) {
    ArrayList<T> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Unit u : units){
        if (specific_unit.isAssignableFrom(u.getClass()) {
            res.add(u);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Simply use a specific type for your generic (`<T>`) instead of a wildcard one (`?`). This is needed to create your return type (`ArrayList<T>`).

Also you should use `isAssignableFrom()` instead of `instanceof`. Please note that `isAssignableFrom()` also checks for subtypes.

Please check this code again as I don't have tested it.

Comment: Why using "T" when the type is irrelevant; and therefore "?" would do?

Comment: @Jägermeister the type `T` is needed to define a new `ArrayList` (the compiler error in the question).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public static <T extends Unit> ArrayList<T> getTheseUnits(Class<T> specific_unit) {
    ArrayList<T> res = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Unit u : units){
        if (specific_unit.isInstance(u)){
            res.add((T) u);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try not to use classes but interfaces in declaration and return (so List instead of ArrayList and Unit instead of SpecificUnit). I've renamed the classes and instances java style... So for example:

```
public static List<? extends Unit> getTheseUnits(Class<? extends Unit> specificUnit, List<Unit> units) {
    List<Unit> res = new ArrayList<Unit>();
    for (Unit u : units){
        if (specificUnit.isInstance(u)){
            res.add(u);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

compiles. Probably it's what you're looking for... let me know if it's useful